# How to plan/prepare for raising a child

Tags: newborn

My partner and I are slowly getting ready to have a child. I think raising a child comes with great responsibility and I'd like to be well prepared.

I'd like to introduce my child to things such as a second language, music, coding etc as soon as possible.

However, I realized I don't even have the slightest idea on how to raise a baby. I've never been around babies for longer than a couple of hours.

How do I know when to feed, when to start teaching language, when to start teaching my child things in general?

How does one get to know these things?
Many of the books etc seem so opinion based. Are there any good factual studies? Guides?

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is off topic for Parenting as it's opinion based. Being a parent is unique and every baby is different. Your midwife/health visitor are there to help you answer these questions. One thing I will say is, it's not as bad as it sounds. There is a **lot** to take in but in my personal experience, just take it in your stride. Don't put so much focus on music, coding, second language, what to teach them _just yet_. This will come with time. Babies just need to be fed and loved. Enjoy them whilst they are babies. Best experience I've ever had is becoming a dad. Good luck.

Comment: Hi, John, and welcome to Parenting. If you can imagine a book written on the subject (and as you have noticed, there actually are many books written on the subject), then it is too broad. We do best with one question at a time. :)

Comment: "How does one get to know these things?" There's no "right" answer out there, because [if there's one thing the research shows, it's that it's not one-size-fits all](http://www.parentingscience.com/responsive-parenting-health-benefits.html). Instead of getting to know the best way to parent, you just need to get to know your baby. :)

Answer (score 2):

These are all great questions but I think some of it you will find to be intuitive. Music is something babies can hear in the womb.

Be careful of volume and little ears.

> How many decibels is safe for a baby? Because your baby cannot tell
>   you how loud is too loud, use a general rule of thumb, that noises
>   less than 80 decibels should not cause hearing damage, according to
>   The Children's Hearing Institute. This is the equivalent to noise in a
>   restaurant or in city street traffic. A normal conversation is about
>   60 decibels.

[LINK How many decibels is safe for a baby?](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiEmIWqsJDTAhXslVQKHXIQAKQQFggfMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.livestrong.com%2Farticle%2F528530-dangerous-noise-levels-for-infants%2F&usg=AFQjCNFgjCHI1TBjO-sPiCf7z3v9SiMloA&sig2=K6LChmvpRJhQR5x1scuvUA&bvm=bv.151426398,bs.1,d.cGc)

[link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjntNbRq5DTAhUH8WMKHWEIBrsQFggyMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.healthline.com%2Fhealth%2Fpregnancy%2Fwhen-can-a-fetus-hear&usg=AFQjCNFFrRN8t1LQzTH9XpgDIDZAfUDPYA&sig2=HlNopnYV373rY54Ib26isw&bvm=bv.151426398,d.cGc)

> Week of Pregnancy/   Development
>
> 9                     /Indentations appear where baby's ears will grow
>
> 18    /Baby starts to hear sound
>
> 24    /Baby is more sensitive to sound
>
> 25-26 /Baby responds to noise/voices in the womb

If you speak more than one language it works very well for infants. [LINK](http://theconversation.com/why-the-baby-brain-can-learn-two-languages-at-the-same-time-57470) Though it at times seems as if the infant is confusing the languages, the research shows that is not the case.

Coding is maths, organisation, and patterning. These are all widely encouraged by the toys made for infants - toddlers -- stacking toys, colour matching -- this can later include letter/number/shapes and item matching and ordering. "Put all the red items here and the blue there."  The level of difficulty is added gradually by adding colours and shapes and so on.

Talk to your infant as if they can respond. "I am making your lunch. I am heating your peas. The peas are green. I like to eat peas. You are eating the green peas. They are small and round." Anything like this will help your child in the long run. Even things they have no reason to know, like your own reading is a good way to keep the language coming. Your car magazine works as well as your fashion mag.

[LINK](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2014/feb/14/talking-to-babies-brain-power-language)